# Notifications on CoreBluetooth returning a CBErrorDomain Code=0

Tags: ios, notifications, core-bluetooth

I am trying to write an app that uses the CoreBluetooth framework.  I am able to search for devices and connect/disconnect to one, and write values to characteristics in the device.  When I try to enable notifications:

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:flag forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

…this triggers:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

However it is always returning the error

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CBErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

I've looked online to see what this could possibly mean.  I've cleaned it, built it again, restarted my iPhone, restarted Xcode, but I keep running into this error.  What does this means and how I can fix it?

Comment: are you getting any other errors in the log? I have this error as well and just before I see this in my logs: `2013-11-12 21:07:27.821 TestApp[29559:303] CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: -536870212`

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting these errors too. I think some of these errors occur when you try to read a value that is marked to only be available through notifications rather than read directly. I don't know what the other values are for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem on iOS6 but not on iOS5? Could be the GATT profile, check the permissions, if they set correctly or not. iOS5 CoreBluetooth ignores some errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the UUID.
2. Check the characteristic's permission. It should be set to notify.